# Jogo da vida c++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, jogos

Olá ! Estou desenvolvendo o jogo da vida e não estou conseguindo fazer com que as regras sejam aplicadas de forma correta(Não sei se é devido à função que imprime ou a função que verifica as regras). Para os que não conhecem, falarei um pouco sobre o jogo abaixo.

A partir de uma configuração inicial de células colocadas em um tabuleiro 2D, pode se observar a evolução dos estados das células através da passagem do tempo, de acordo com as regras definidas.Cada célula possui 8 vizinhos, sendo estes todas as células adjacentes. Além disso possuem dois possíveis estados: viva ou morta. Estes estados são modificados a cada instante do jogo, de forma a estar sempre de acordo com as regras. Cada atualização do estado de todas as células num instante de tempo constitui em uma geração. A partir desses conceitos é possível entender as quatro regras básicas do Jogo.

Regras:
Qualquer célula viva com menos de dois vizinhos vivos morre de solidão.
Qualquer célula viva com mais de três vizinhos vivos morre de superpopulação.
Qualquer célula morta com exatamente três vizinhos vivos se torna uma célula viva.
Qualquer célula viva com dois ou três vizinhos vivos continua no mesmo estado para a próxima geração.

Abaixo seguem os códigos somente das funções que verificam/imprimem a matriz nos arquivos matriz.hpp e matriz.cpp. Caso necessário, eu envio o restante do código.

```
#ifndef MATRIZ_HPP
#define MATRIZ_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Matriz{

private:
char matriz[80][80];
char prox_geracao[80][80];
int quantidade_linhas;
int quantidade_colunas;

public:
Matriz();
int quantidade_geracoes;
int escolher_forma();
void insere_Linhas();
int  getLinhas();
void insere_Colunas();
int getColunas();
void cria_Matriz();
void verifica_regras();
void imprime_matriz();
};
#endif




void Matriz::verifica_regras(){
int linhas = getLinhas();
int colunas = getColunas();
int vizinhos =0;
int i=0;
int j=0;

memcpy(prox_geracao, matriz , sizeof(prox_geracao[80]));

for(i=0;i<linhas;i++)
{
prox_geracao[i][j] = matriz[i][j];

for(j=0;j<colunas;j++)
{
  vizinhos =0;
  for(int k=-1;k<2;k++)
  {
    for(int l=-1; l<2; l++)
    {
      if(matriz[i+k][j+l] == 'o')
        vizinhos++;
    }
  }
    if((vizinhos < 2 || vizinhos > 3) && matriz[i][j] == 'o' )
      prox_geracao[i][j] = '-';


    else if(vizinhos == 3 && matriz[i][j] == '-' ){
      prox_geracao[i][j] = 'o';
    }

    else if((vizinhos == 2 || vizinhos == 3) && matriz[i][j] == 'o'){
      prox_geracao[i][j] = 'o';
    }
    else
      prox_geracao[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
}
}
memcpy(matriz, prox_geracao , sizeof(matriz[80]));
}

void Matriz::imprime_matriz(){
int linhas = getLinhas();
int colunas = getColunas();

cout << "\n";

for(int i=0 ; i<linhas ; i++){
for(int j=0; j<colunas ; j++){
  cout << prox_geracao[i][j] ;
}
cout << "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: E qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Não estou sabendo aonde o problema se encontra, pois as regras não estão funcionando corretamente

Comment: Que problema? No texto não ficou claro que problema você fala

Comment: Os elementos vizinhos não estão sendo contados corretamente

Comment: Indentação de código é uma boa... Melhora a legibilidade! Dica: leia o [Guia Rápido de Boas Práticas em C++](https://github.com/kelvins/Boas-Praticas-Cplusplus).